# Bash Sorting a List by Columns

Tags: bash, list, sorting, awk, sed

I'm reverse sorting column 2.
As for column 1, if multiple lines have the same $2 value, I want them to be sorted in a reverse order. I have stored this list in a variable at the moment in a bash script. Is there a sed or awk function to be used?

My output right now, for example, is:

```
123, 3
124, 3
12345, 2
898, 1
1010, 1
```

what I want is:

```
124, 3
123, 3
12345, 2
1010, 1
898, 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Would not `sort -t, -k2,2nr -k1,1nr <<<"var"` fit the bill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of Perl one-liners and `sort`. The one-liners convert the `,`  delimiter into tab (and back). And `sort` uses the `-r` option for reverse, and `-g` option for numeric sort. Option `-kN,N` specifies to sort just by field `N`, here 2nd, then 1st field.

```
perl -pe 's/, /\t/' in_file | sort -k2,2gr -k1,1gr | perl -pe 's/\t/, /' > out_file
```

For example:

Create example input file:

```
cat > foo <<EOF
123, 3
124, 3
12345, 2
898, 1
1010, 1
EOF
```

Run the command:

```
cat foo | perl -pe 's/, /\t/' | sort -k2,2gr -k1,1gr | perl -pe 's/\t/, /'
```

Output:

```
124, 3
123, 3
12345, 2
1010, 1
898, 1
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: I was able to pipeline using "sort -k2,2gr -k1,1gr " and it worked out great! thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trivial `awk` script, but it's not hard either. You simply use an array `a[]` below, to store the values for the first field for equal values of the second field. If `last` is set (e.g. not the first record) and the second field changes, you output the current array and reset the array (that is Rule 1).

In Rule 2, you just scan through the existing array and insert the current first field in the array in order. You keep the `last` value of the second field so you know when it changes. You use the `END` rule to output the last set of values, e.g.

```
awk -F, '
    last && $2 != last {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            print a[i]", "last;
        delete a
        n = 0
    }
    {
        swapped=0
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            if ($1 > a[i]) {
                swapped=1
                for (j=n+1; j>i; j--)
                    a[j]=a[j-1]
                a[i]=$1
            }
        if (!swapped)
            a[++n]=$1
        else
            n++
        last=$2
    }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        print a[i]", "last
    }
' file
```

The `swapped` flag just tells you whether the current first-field was inserted into the array before an existing element (`swapped == 1`) or if it was just added at the end (`swapped == 0`).

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample file in the file named `file`, you can simply change to the directory that contains it, select the script above with the mouse (change the filename to what yours is) and then *middle-mouse-paste* the script into the terminal, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, '
>     last && $2 != last {
>         for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
>             print a[i]", "last;
>         delete a
>         n = 0
>     }
>     {
>         swapped=0
>         for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
>             if ($1 > a[i]) {
>                 swapped=1
>                 for (j=n+1; j>i; j--)
>                     a[j]=a[j-1]
>                 a[i]=$1
>             }
>         if (!swapped)
>             a[++n]=$1
>         else
>             n++
>         last=$2
>     }
> END {
>     for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
>         print a[i]", "last
>     }
> ' file
124,  3
123,  3
12345,  2
1010,  1
898,  1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: do you think there's a way to do this without arrays?

Comment: Not in a single call to `awk`. If you don't use arrays, you will be spawning additional processes piping partial output to be sorted, etc.. and then in putting the results back together. The single array allows the first-field values to be inserted in-order, effectively providing the sort that way. `awk` has arrays by default -- why would you not want to use them?

Comment: I want to find multiple ways to perform one task and I'm experimenting with the versatility of pipelining, thanks for your input!

Comment: No worries -- that is a great way to learn. The big consideration is efficiency. Every pipe and every other process requires you to spawn an additional subshell which duplicates read, etc.. If there are just a few thousand lines of input -- then it's largely a wash, if there are 90,000,000 lines, that is the difference in a single call finishing in 60 seconds or multiple processes taking 10X (or more) that amount of time. Learn all the differing ways you can, and learn the distinctions between the methods -- that's how you learn to use the proper tool for any job....

Comment: If you spawn multiple subshell within a loop, then performance will be orders of magnitude worse. Minimizing the number of subshells is key.

Comment: I appreciate all this advice, I'm a bash newbie

Comment: You are welcome -- good luck with your scripting! Also, while it is a bit daunting at first, learning `sed` and `awk` are well worth your efforts. `awk` is by far the Swiss-Army Knife of text processing, See [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents_)

Answer (score -1):

Also with `awk`, you can try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; OFS=FS="\n"} {tmp2 = $2; $2 = $1; $1 = tmp2; tmp5=$5; $5=$4; $4=tmp5}1' file
124, 3
123, 3
12345, 2
1010, 1
898, 1
```